# If user denies consent it isn't possible to serve non-personalised ads, instead ads don't show at all

Tags: flutter, admob

I am using the google_mobile_ads: ^3.0.0 plugin.

I have followed the documentation at https://developers.google.com/admob/flutter/eu-consent to add EU consent to my app using the Google UMP SDK.

The app is successfully collecting consent or no consent from the user.

If the user consents to personalised ads, then the ads show in my app.

If the user denies consent, then no ads show. There appears to be no way to serve non-personalised ads.

The debug log shows:

I/Ads ( 1433): Ad failed to load : 3

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find any solution? At least we should be able to show non-targeted ads right?

Comment: Take a look at: https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk/c/MkX6n49Z3yU

Comment: did you find a way or still buggy ?

Comment: All Google AdMob ads use cookies. If a user denies consent for cookies, then no ads will be shown. See the above link for discussion on the matter.

Comment: Our problem is that although the message: `Ad failed to load 3` appears, the `onAdFailedToLoad` method of the callback is not called. The equivalent callbacks in AdMob on iOS *are* called.

Comment: If no consent is given through UMP, Google will serve limited ads to the app. In the link of the 2nd reply Google admit that limited ads actually mean they won't serve any ads at all. This is why it's important to know (a) what the user selected and (b) when it fails to load the ad, so you can do something else to get revenue.

Comment: I have the same issue with the callback as Dave Nottage, but only on Android. Is anyone else seeing that callback firing?